# Fastest way in R to read and compare CSV files

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I know there are other questions on stack overflow about fastest way of reading csv files in R - and they have been answered; data.table seems to be the way to go. But I have additional requirements.

I need to come up with a script that does set operation of diff between two groups of vectors (to find the count of values that match in both vectors). Both group of vectors are to be fetched from csv files in two different directories, dirA and dirB. Each vector in dirA will be compared with all the vectors in dirB and number of matches will be recorded. dirA has about 50 files and dirB has 3000 files of varying size (1 to 60 MBs).

Below is my attempt at it using R. It is not as fast as I would expect (compared to a similar solution implemented in Pandas this code is 30% slower). One go at reading 3000 files is taking more than 120 seconds. Is there something I am missing or this is about the best I can get in R - my be by clever use of vectorization and multiple comparisons in one go? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

- I am using data.table version 1.13.6.
- I want to read everything as string (there are leading zeros and some other anomalies)

Code:

```
path_dirA <- "data/processed_data_dirA"
path_dirB <- "data/processed_data_dirB"

fn_dirA <- list.files(here(path_dirA), pattern="csv")
fn_dirB <- list.files(here(path_dirB), pattern="csv")
v_count_matched <- integer()

for (fn1 in fn_dirA) {
  f1 <- data.table::fread(here(fn_dirA, fn1), colClasses = 'character')
 
  for (fn2 in fn_dirB) {
    f2 <- data.table::fread(here(fn_dirB, fn2), colClasses = 'character')
    v_count_matched <- c(v_count_matched, length( fintersect(f1[,1],f2[,1]) ) )

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In some cases `vroom` is faster than data.table for ingesting files, since it indexes them for lazy loading. Might be worth a shot. https://github.com/r-lib/vroom

Comment: Rather than concatenating ``length( fintersect(f1[,1],f2[,1]) )`` to ``v_count_matched`` each iteration of the loop, create a vector ``v_count_matched`` which is the length of ``fn_dirA`` and fill it like ``v_count_matched[fn1] = length( fintersect(f1[,1],f2[,1]) )``.

Comment: Check out Circle 2 of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). THe problem might be with the constant appending rather than reading the file.

Comment: If you are only comparing the first column, you could read only that column (in `fread` with the `select` parameter).

Comment: Try updating `data.table`, there are some recent performance improvements that _may_ impact your case.

Comment: Besides that, what is the total size of all of the files? You should prioritize reading the largest files once & once only. e.g. if dirB has all the large files, you are inefficiently reading them repeatedly `length(dirA)` times. Simply switching the loop order would be an improvement. More sophistication is possible.

Comment: More generally, a column-oriented data storage like parquet seems better-suited to your task, but that is a much wider lens to approach your problem.

Comment: @jon: vroom is not giving improved results.

Comment: @user438383, MrFlick: will give it a try

Comment: @crestor: these are single column files with unique values in them

Comment: @MichaelChirico: let me try your first two suggestions. total size is ~1.2 GB. some files are considerably bigger. i used this approach of loading a single file to keep the script generic because file size can change and loading multiple files at once may overwhelm RAM unexpectedly.

THANK YOU ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, most of the time is consumed reading the CSV files.
If you could cache on disk those CSV files in another format with faster read times, you would obtain maximal savings.

For example, if you need to repeat the comparisons daily but only one CSV has changed.

You could have those CSV files saved (cached on disk) in `fst` format. https://www.fstpackage.org/

Comment: `vroom` package is not useful in this case because its advantage is lazy loading. But you really need to read all the content from the files.

Comment: The set of files in folder B do not change that often. Converting them over to fst is helping a lot and actually saved the most time; accepting this answer. The other answers also helped build my understanding. So Thank You ALL.

Answer (score 1):

One possible speed-up would be to use indexes to add data rather than concatenating:

```
fn_dirA <- list.files(here(path_dirA), pattern="csv")
fn_dirB <- list.files(here(path_dirB), pattern="csv")
v_count_matched <- vector(NA, length(fn_dirA)*length(n_dirA))


counter = 0
for (fn1 in fn_dirA) {
  f1 <- data.table::fread(here(fn_dirA, fn1), colClasses = 'character')
 
  for (fn2 in fn_dirB) {
    counter = counter + 1
    f2 <- data.table::fread(here(fn_dirB, fn2), colClasses = 'character')
    v_count_matched[counter] <- length( fintersect(f1[,1],f2[,1]))

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted an answer based on what worked previously. However, I was able to reduce the execution time greatly by simply adding setkey. The whole thing is taking 6 hours now instead of days!